# Power Supply for two 50V/12.5A Solenoids

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, solenoid, ac-dc, high-current

I'm in the planning stages of building a custom pinball table and one of the sticking points is powering the flipper coils. They're 50V DC coils with a resistance of only 4 ohms during the stroke. That's 12.5 amps, and there are two of them so potentially up to 25 amps.

However, they are only high power for the length of the stroke, when an "end of stroke" switch uses the full coil resulting in 133 ohms resistance bringing it down to a much smaller 0.376 amps which is all it needs to hold the flippers up.

"Real" pinball machines use a massive transformer with a full bridge rectifier. They're unregulated (I believe), which is fine, and have several taps for other voltages I'm not concerned with generating (much easier ways). But I'm not having much luck finding something similar for the 48-50 volts that isn't several hundred bucks.

Trying to design something though I'm not sure what to aim for. The 12.5 amps (each) is for such a short duration it seems like overkill to design something that can handle that much power continuously. However, I don't know how a modern switching power supply would handle such an impulse. I feel like it would think there is a short circuit and shut down to protect itself.

I've heard of people using ATX power supplies from PC's, just daisy chaining 4 of them together to get the +12V rails up to 48V (which is close enough). These can be had for fairly cheap (~$15/ea) and have a lot of power (25+ amps).

How would these handle an impulse load like that? Can they be connected serially without other issues? Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1):

Problem with SMPS is the pulse current rating is usually not much more than the average current rating, so you'll end up paying for a very powerful supply that you will only use when pushing the buttons on your pinball.

Unlike a SMPS, a transformer can be overloaded without trouble, as long as duty cycle remains low. It's heavy, so it takes a while to overheat.

The cheapest source for this sort of transformer is an old audio amplifier pulled out of a dumpster. If it's a 50W amp, wiring both secondaries in series should give close enough to 50-60V. You'll also get a few aged capacitors for free. Before stripping it for parts, look online to see if it's not a collector's model though...

Another option would be a few used 12V lead acid batteries, with a low power 48V supply as float charger. In this case the batteries are used a bit like capacitors. They don't need to be in top shape, so you could also get them for free.

Answer (score 0):

First, you might not need that full 12.5 ampere, because a solenoid has inductance, and your computation is for the maximum current after some time. The solenoid will act quick and short, so the actual current will be lower.

The current is further lowered when the solenoid is moving, generating a back-emf. After movement, the limit switch will increase the resistance to keep the steady state current low, as you mentioned.

Then, you might not need 50 V. What the solenoid needs to get moving is current, not voltage. So why not charge a nice inductor with, say, 5 A and force that through the solenoid? Like the answer of Drew, but then different. Effectively transforming a low voltage of 5V to a higher voltage over the solenoid.

[image]

An ATX power supply gives lots of amperes at 5 volt. Make sure the DC resistance of L1 limits the current to something like 5 A. When you open the switch, the current through L1 will continue through the diode and the solenoid.

The inductance of the solenoid might cause the voltage to rise to, say, 50 V, but who cares. The amperes will make the solenoid to move, which is what you want.

You might want to implement the switch with a FET transistor, which might be cheaper than a mechanical switch. And to control your pin-bal machine you probably use more stuff, like an arduino, which might interface nicely with a FET. But that are implementation details. Main point is just try an inductor L1 and a modest power supply instead of overkill 50 VDC and 12.5 A.

Good Luck!

Comment: This will not work. A reasonable inductor will not store enough energy to run the solenoid for 10s of milliseconds. Additionally this circuit wouldn't be compatible with the existing solenoid controls.

Comment: Then use a bigger inductor. Size will be comparable to the solenoid. Nice thing is you can use a (1) cheap ATX PSU. Problem, though, is, after pushing the flippers, it cannot hold the flippers up. But this is a fun circuit

Answer (score 0):

ATX supplies are no good for this.

First of all, ATX supplies cannot be connected in series, unless their internal circuitry is modified so that the output ground is floating, or they are left ungrounded at the mains side, which again is something that should not be done.

Another thing is they barely work when only one of the output voltages is loaded, and they work extremely poorly with pulsed loads, especially if the load is suddenly just disconnected. So they need a lot of extra work to make them able to handle arbitary pulsed loads from single output voltage.

Almost any other solution would be simpler, like having a capacitor to provide the large surge current and smoothing the current taken from supply with an inductor.

Answer (score -1):

A transformer is probably the simplest option. It doesn't need to be exactly "110 in 50 out". Transformers are ratiometric, so you just need about 2:1. I would get a 110 to 230v transformer and run it in reverse. 110 * (110/230) = 52.6v. I saw some cheap, high power transformers that fit the bill on ebay.

You almost definetly can't hook up 4 atx power supplies in series, because they're probably grounded.

You may be able to use a smaller power supply, plus a cap bank. You're correct the supply will probably trip almost instantly if you overdraw it, even with a bunch of caps. The reason is that for the caps to provide power, the voltage has to drop. If the supply is any good, it's going to fight that drop and basically take the whole load itself.

The way to counteract this is to place a beefy current limiting resistor between the power supply and the caps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flZTsG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Calculating the exact resistor is actually kind of tricky. But you can just buy a handful of 1 ohm power resistors and figure it out by trial and error. You could also play around with a circuit simulation, but you'll need to know the coils inductance. I think if you click on this schematic it'll bring up circuit labs, which has a simulation feature.

Simulation of the circuit [here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3AWAnC1b0DYQGZpgOwbYoBM2AHBmOddgiAKySMgLaMCmAtGGAFABnEOQTkcJZkjAlxzZhABmAQwA2AjnwBujJDIRwdM7BKin9rMXKjQGfAO6HZIDPiMnIfAE7hIDLMflffxEzPhUfPxwQsCDWUVMYSCQE%20xApN0DIMQCoVJisp3zsyHoPByKcEoj-KrLqyvoYyJy6pqwEePxsdvi6hl04sX69Aw9vFwyQLv93YVTpwccOy1SRbJMFlr4AYynupwXlhLwLWHhzi7B6UT4Ae3BnUtYk-BZE%20CRCPxIGUxkIbB3ViPMwvaznQgkJDEBAMbDSX7vOCfDDfX4QPQ4PhAA)

Comment: If you have a 48V DC supply, you don't need the capacitor and resistor at all. Just close the button for a short moment and the solenoid will operate. The inductance will limit the inrush current. In fact, there is no inrush current. The current will increase from zero to a maximum value dependent on the DC resistance of the solenoid, but way before coming close to max, the solenoid is done moving and you can open the switch. What you DO need is a commutation diode over the solenoid to avoid a voltage surge when opening the switch, which might cause arcs over the switch and ruin the contacts.

Comment: Have you tried a simulation? I would guess that is not possible, because a switch in series with an inductance gives rise to an equation that is impossible to solve, a "singularity". Nice drawing, though

Comment: I can assure you that a beefy solenoid can trip a PSU, I've done it before. I was missing the flyback diode, which I've added.

Comment: By your logic, motor inrush current isn't a thing, since motors also have a significant inductance. The fact is that that may reduce the current for some microseconds, but the solenoid will be running for much longer than that.

Comment: motor inrush current isn't because of the inductance -- it's because the rotor has inertia and takes some time to come to rotate fast enough to generate enough back e.m.f. to lower the input current.

Comment: @jp314 Yes I know. That's the point I'm trying to make. The inrush current takes place over an (electrically) long time. The inductance of the load is relatively insignificant for DC current calculations.

Comment: Nobody asked for a DC current calculation. When you close the switch, you don't get "DC", but a transient. What is an "electrically" long time? Where does the value of 50 mH come from? The good point of your solution is using one PS of 48V. R1 and C1 just add cost and losses.

Comment: @Roland It's the inductance of the solenoid. I don't have his but I measured a valve I have lying around and it was 90mH, so using that value he would reach 90% of the dc current after 36mS. So yes the DC values are relevant. Play around with it in a simulator if you don't believe me.

Comment: Add an 8 ohm charging resistor and you can drive solenoid at nearly 100% power for 150mS and only draw 2A peak from the PSU (not counting switch on).

Comment: https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3AWAnC1b0DYQGZpgOwbYoBM2AHBmOddgiAKySMgLaMCmAtGGAFABnEOQTkcJZkjAlxzZhABmAQwA2AjnwBujJDIRwdM7BKin9rMXKjQGfAO6HZIDPiMnIfAE7hIDLMflffxEzPhUfPxwQsCDWUVMYSCQE+xApN0DIMQCoVJisp3zsyHoPByKcEoj-KrLqyvoYyJy6pqwEePxsdvi6hl04sX69Aw9vFwyQLv93YVTpwccOy1SRbJMFlr4AYynupwXlhLwLWHhzi7B6UT4Ae3BnUtYk-BZE+CRCPxIGUxkIbB3ViPMwvaznQgkJDEBAMbDSX7vOCfDDfX4QPQ4PhAA

Comment: The mistake most non-tech people make is thinking of the solenoid as an inductor. This solenoid is setting something in motion, so should be seen as an ohmic load, with a parasitic series induction. When there is no motion, the ohmic load is small, just the resistance of the copper windings. When in motion, the ohmic load is much higher due to back-emf. A good, efficient, solenoid should have a low windings resistance and low series induction, compared to the ohmic load during movement. (Also, when movement stops, the end switch will add more R). Same principle as with motors and transformers.

Comment: In my experience solenoids are very very inefficient. I guess one of us would have to hook one up to a scope to settle it.